# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) in Python application

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have written an python program which basically interacts with Google Cloud Storage Buckets. I wanted to read the the contents of multiple JSON files(At present I can read one JSON file pretty easily).However I am facing an issue. Here's my code.

```
credential_path = "xyz.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path
os.environ['GCS_API_KEY'] = "164641r3t4fcvfsv564"


storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'NAME'
file = '2021-03-05'
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=file)
for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
    data = json.loads(blob.download_as_string(client=None))
    print(data)
```

So what This piece of code does is that it reads the entire bucket with the file '2021-03-05' and simply prints the names of json files and their contents.
The issue I am facing is found here:

```
File "app.py", line 19, in <module>
    data = json.loads(blob.download_as_string(client=None))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have tried working with a json.load() or with read() however that didn't work. Please help me out. How can I loop through all the files and get their names and read their content? Please help.

Comment: the output of `blob.download_as_string(client=None)` is probably not json.

Comment: @VishalSingh how do I proceed further then?

Comment: You check what the actual output is and find out why it is not what expected.

Comment: Try printing out some of the  data returned by `blob.download_as_string(client=None)`, e.g. `data = blob.download_as_string(); print(data[:100])`. Also `download_as_string()` is deprecated. That wouldn't be the problem, but you should use `download_as_bytes()` in new code.

Comment: @mhawke that is exactly what I wanted. Thanks. It worked!